# Calculate date(april) - 10 months (which would be previous year now)

Tags: db2

```
   Date(04-04-2013) - 10 month  ( must give date which should be 06-04-2012)
```

I need to get data between previous 10 months to current date i.e. April.
The year will change -1, so getting problem.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant to be a replacement for looking things up in the manual.  Please refer to IBM's DB2 Information Center, if your server is running on Linux, Unix, Windows, or z/OS.  See the IBM i Information Center if the server is running IBM i or OS/400.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what your question is exactly, but I think you just want to get data from a table between now and 10 months ago. This should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_date BETWEEN (CURRENT DATE - 10 MONTHS) AND (CURRENT DATE)
```

You don't have to worry about it being a different year, because the date calculation (`- 10 MONTHS`) will handle all of that.